# convert date from yyyymmdd to yyyy/mm/dd formate using angular pipe html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is there any option available in angular to convert yyyymmdd format date to yyyy/mm/dd directly.

I have tried using angular pipe but it is giving different date.

my date is 20201029

{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}

Comment: 20201029 or is a string or is a number (but it's not the millisecondns after 1970/1/1), anycase you need make yourself a pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations

Comment: @Tibebes A string can be passed to the pipe as long as Angular is able to parse it. The problem is, that 20201029 can't be parsed. `new Date('20201029' )` returns an invalid date. The result is the same, he needs to convert his string to a date object beforehand

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm The solution I've just provided deals with string manipulation (custom pipe). No conversion is required

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom pipe to deal with string.

try doing something like this:

```
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customDate'
})
export class CustomDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    const pattern = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/
    const [year, month, day] = value.match(pattern).slice(1)

    return [year, month, day].join('-')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is many custom formatting and/or forms in your app, check for [ngx-mask](https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page/main#).
You'll find Pipes in the "Other" section.
If this is the only case, a custom pipe is your solution.